# Image size of Woocommerce variation

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I have a problem with  variable product in woocommerce. The product only has 2 variations (two Sizes).

My single product page uses a custom image_size (dd_single_image) which is width: 900 height: 1200 crop: True. Using product-page.php I have set the products to use dd_single_image (DD-Mens-499-900x1200.jpg). It works and displays great!

Functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'dd_single_image', 900, 1200, true );
```

product-image.php

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $html  = '<div data-thumb="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'dd_single_image' ) . '" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><a href="' . esc_url( $full_size_image[0] ) . '">';
        $html .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'dd_single_image', $attributes );
        $html .= '</a></div>';
```

Each variation DOES NOT have an image set up, they don't need a separate image and can happily use the product image already set.

However, as soon as you choose a size variation from the dropdown menu (select) it switches the image src to use a different image file (DD-Mens-495-416x278.jpg). This is not cropped and is, obviously, smaller.

I've looked through variation.php, variable.php, add-to-cart-variation.js and many more. I've searched and tried and banged my head against the wall.

If anyone can shed light on this, it would be very, very gratefully received. Thanks in advance

http://159.65.19.143/product/navy-sheep/

Running Wordpress 4.9.3 | Woocommerce 3.3.0 | Child theme of Storefront

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the image sizes at **WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display** as well?

Comment: Those settings aren’t available to me. They’re just not there. Not sure why - I’ve tried to find that out also but with no result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your code for the initial output. The problem is the form carries the metadata for all the variations including the path to the images so when you change the variation by choosing the size it updates the image based on what it has in the form "data-product_variations" attribute. 
You need to find the template that is generating this to modify which image size it lists here.

If you can tell me which plugin you are using for multiple variation images I might be able to help further.

Comment: I’m not using a plugin other that WooCommerce itself. The product is just a Variable Product that comes as standard. I agree that the form is choosing it but I have no idea where that’s coming from. I initially thought it would be via add-to-cart-variation.js (and .min.js) but I don’t seem to be able to control it via that. That file seems to control the select dropdown itself but not the form that it’s contained in. 

Any further insight would be awesome!

Comment: I'm still continuing to struggle with how that image size is being generated. On my list of registered image sizes there are two - woocommerce_single and shop_single that are listed as being 416x278 - the exact size that the variation is displaying. I have removed them using remove_image_size and deleted the 'DD-Mens-495-416x278.jpg' from uploads but refreshing the product page regenerates 'DD-Mens-495-416x278.jpg'.